# Combine Video and Audio Streams (Qt, OpenCV, PortAudio,libsnd?)

Tags: c++, video, audio, opencv, portaudio

I was wondering, how would I combine recorded audio and video into one if I have them in separate files? Preferably using OpenCV and PortAudio/libsnd.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg is used to decode and encode almost all popular formats.  It can be used as an alternative to all of these. PortAudio will probably only be useful for audio playback, so unless you need to play the stuff back it won't be needed.  In case you do need A/V playback, FFmpeg is also good (VLC uses it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer ffmpeg

Comment: So many libraries =/ Can it be used instead of libsndfile, do you think?

Answer (score 0):

On linux try mencoder usually part of the mplayer package. It is fairly straight forward to use after reading through its man page.